# jquery validation & id's ft numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I have a form which uses various numbers from salesforce e.g:

```
Landing Page:<input  id="00NF0000008Mrcm" maxlength="40" name="00NF0000008Mrcm" size="20" type="text" /><br>
```

here is my jquery:

```
$("#requestInfo").validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        '00NF0000008Mrcm': {
            selectNone: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        first_name: 'Please enter your first name',
        last_name: 'Please enter your last name',
        email: 'Please enter your email address',
        00NF0000008Mrcm: 'Please enter your telephone number'
    }
});
```

but these fields spout out an error in firebug on the console and ultimately won't validate, upon renaming the rules in the validation js and the id in the html it works, however then because its from salesforce (an external leads script) which generates the code, it won't go into the leads system, how can I make the code validate?

Here is the console error: `invalid property id [Break On This Error] 00NF0000008Mrcm: { selectNone: true }`

Thanks

Comment: It's possible it's due to the `id` and `name` beginning with a number, which is invalid.

Comment: ID's are not allowed to start with a number, classes do.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I looked before posting the question but I did find this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675951/jquery-form-validation-problem-salesforce-field-id-starts-with-digit

but that didn't work.

Here is the console error:

invalid property id
[Break On This Error]  

00NF0000008Mrcm: { selectNone: true }

I also suspect its down to the id and name being a number, I can't change the code which salesforce outputs and neither will the developers, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the rule in a different way :

```
// first setup the normal validation
$("#requestInfo").validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        first_name: 'Please enter your first name',
        last_name: 'Please enter your last name',
        email: 'Please enter your email address'
    }
});
// then add your custom id based validation
$("#00NF0000008Mrcm").rules("add", {
    selectNone: true,
    messages: {
        selectNone: 'Please enter your telephone number'
    }
});
```

Working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/JpsxY/

Comment: @GrahamBarnes what errors / problems are you getting with this code ? as you can see from the demo - it works

Comment: The code was missing a bracket ) after the last } either way it doesn't validate the form and there is no error in the console on firebug anymore which is odd