# Adding own rule in jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have next jquery code:

```
$("input").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: 'Please enter your telephone number'
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log('bob');
        element.insertBefore(error);
    }
});
```

I am trying to add new rule like in answer in this question : [jquery validation & id's ft numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174788/jquery-validation-ids-ft-numbers) 
I have such html code:

```
<form method='post' action='' id='#countersForm'>
<input id="88" class="counter_input active" type="text" enabled="">
<input id="89" class="counter_input active" type="text" enabled="">
</form>
```

My problems are:

1) Why browser tries to validate field on page loaded? I don't need this (message bob appeaing on page load.

2) Why only first input field is validating? I want to validate all fields.

3) Why console says , that element is not defined?

[documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#options) says that element parameter contain validated element. `console.log(element)` says that it is undefiened. Why?

Comment: Maybe not the issue but nontheless: use valid `id` values (don't begin with a digit or hash character, also mentioned in your linked post). Also `enabled` isn't a thing.

Comment: Best is to setup a jsFiddle..I started one for you : http://jsfiddle.net/dEWEm/ please complete..it would be best.

Comment: In addition to what has been said give each input a name attribute. I have seen some wonky behavior from un-named inputs.

Comment: Sad. Just left home. I will end jsfiddle later, add name attribute and change id-s to `id-xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers and comments.

I solved my problem. Working code (current problem is solved) is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2LRv7/2/

There was a huge mistake in my js code. I put `errorPlacement` section to the rules function. I have to put this option to `.validate` section.

```
$("#countersForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        console.log(error);
        var br = $( "<br>" );
        error.insertAfter(element);
        br.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

Also, as @TilwinJoy said, I used `$('input').rules(/*....*/)` wrong. I had to use `each` function.

This code is okay:

```
$("input").each(function () { // next code will affect all input fields
    $(this).rules("add", { // $(this) is my input field
    required: true,
        digits: true,
        messages: {
            required: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения',
            digits: 'В поле могут быть только цифры'
        }
    });
});
```

Current problem solved, but I have another. If you want to help check this question: [Class is not being added to the error element on first check , but when field is being checked again all going ok (jquery validation plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487828/class-is-not-being-added-to-the-error-element-on-first-check-but-when-field-is)

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/):

> Read, add and remove rules for an element.

it says 'an' element. `$('input')`  in your case returns two elements.

validation plugin uses `name` attribute of elements, your element's doesn't have names.

You have to initialize the plugin using `validate()` method on the `form` you want to validate, for e.g.

```
$("#myform").validate({ //where my form is the id of your form
 rules: {
  name: "required", //name is the name of your element
 },
 messages: {
 }
});
```

Comment: Why I have duplicate id? I have id 89 and 88. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: True. But names would be variables for each user. First one has counters with id's 55 65, another has id's 777 888 etc. I had found solution, which is presented in my question.

Comment: i use this same method to validate my forms too. you are right.

Comment: @LeandroRuel who is right? Can you suggest code from your site then? Or write simple working example. Or you meant Tilwin? The problem I have variable names, not static, read previous comment. If you have same comp give an example please. Thank you.

Comment: you are generating these fields with any language at backend?

Comment: @LeandroRuel Yes , with php

Comment: @TilwinJoy I added answer for question.