# Class is not being added to the error element on first check , but when field is being checked again all going ok (jquery validation plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Look my js and html code there: http://jsfiddle.net/2LRv7/2/

There are 1 problem. Don't write anything in inputs, just press submit button. There are error messages blocks appears after both inputs. They are surrounded by yellow border, but they must be surrounded with yellow border and on pink background. Message class wasn't added.

If you click send button again or click on field and click somewhere else (out of field) or click somewhere on page just after first validating block style will be changed (background turns pink).

I don't know why, but message class doesn't add to the label element classes. This action specified in highligh/dehighligh block (5-12 lines of js part).

I am not sure, but I think error is somewhere in this lanes:

```
    $("#countersForm").validate({
        debug: true,
        validClass: "active",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass).addClass('message');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass).removeClass('message');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            console.log(error);
            var br = $( "<br>" );
            error.insertAfter(element);
            br.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: @you might want to accept answers for the previous questions that helped you before asking new ones..

Comment: You don't answered my question (last one I mean), your answer didn't help me to solve MY problem at all (thats why it wasn't accepted). I have variable names, as I said 2-3 times. I wanted delete question, because I solved my problem, but I couldn't because of your answer. Also, you said about `$('input')` returns some objects, not one — I knew this, but used `rules` not correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the error class in `errorPlacement` function

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2LRv7/5/)

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        console.log(error);
        var br = $( "<br>" );
        error.insertAfter(element).addClass('message');
        br.insertAfter(element);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you satisfied now ? :) That is answer for asked question, so it is accepted. I knew, that the problem was somewhere here :) 
I figured that `highlight` not working with first call. Thank you.

Comment: Hm. Just realised this is not so good as I think. Check [YOUR FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2LRv7/5/). Focus first input field and type some not digital symbols, error will not appear. When you click somewhere on page, error will appear. Now delete all from input field. Try to type some not digitals. Now input validating on each keypress. Why validating don't works on each keypress first time?

Comment: After that, check [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LRv7/6/). I added remote rule. I don't know why, but now if I input something invalid - error is appearing (not only invalid because of remote). If I make input data valid, classes of error label are deleting, but error label is still shown, but must be `display: none;`. Whats wrong again :((((